# Opencart google_sitemap URL

Tags: cron, sitemap, opencart

I'm using Open cart in my website.
I want to run a cron job for these urls

- `http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap`
- `http://www.mywebsite/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap/mainIndexXml`

How to specify these URL's into cron manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `wget` depending on your privileges. That said I don't understand exactly why you would be running these though I'm guessing you want to get the caches for them updated periodically?